# How to find the elements inside the QuerySets

Tags: python, django, mongodb

If i have two models:

```
Model_1.objects.all()

Model_2.objects.all()
```

Model_1 contains all the elements, Model_2 contains a part of these elements.

How can i find the elements contained in Model_1 but not in Model_2?

I tried:

```
Model_1.objects.exclude(pk=Model_2.objects.order_by('pk'))
```

It doesn't work.

Comment: can you share us your both models?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, 2 models represent two different entities. But if you want to filter the Model_1 based on some property of Model_2
Use exclude and filter as per your requirement.

> Model_1.objects.exclude(id__in=Model_2.objects.all())
> Model_1.objects.filter(id__in=Model_2.objects.all())

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`in[Django doc.]`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#in) like:

```py
Model_1.objects.exclude(pk__in=[obj.pk for obj in Model_2.objects.all()])
```